# Compress XML data with C

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing

What is the best way to compress XML data with C? Is there any Linux internal library that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: There is no best way. If you need to compress something `zlib` is usually enough.

Comment: Remember that XML is simply text.  Anything that can be used to compress plain text will also work with XML, and there are a wide variety of compression routines available for Linux.  Do you have any special requirements that you have to meet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The venerable [zlib](http://zlib.net/) library is widely available on Linux systems, generally as part of the base install, and is eminently suitable for compressing XML.

Answer (score 0):

[mod_gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/install.htm) is available in linux....